# Dynamically changing images connected to the item in listbox

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to dynamically display image of selected item in listbox.
The name of the image store in folder is exactly like item with index [0] from my tuple in listbox

```
list1= Listbox(ViewFrame, height=15, width=75)      
files = glob.glob('img\\*.jpg')     
ImageFrame = LabelFrame(page1, text="Podgląd i parametry")
ImageFrame.grid(row=6, column=6, pady=10, padx=5)
path = files[list1.curselection()[0]]
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
label = Label(ImageFrame)
label.image = img
label.configure(image=img)
```

Error:

> path = files[list1.curselection()[0]]
>
> IndexError: tuple index out of range

It seems to me that before I open the app nothing is selected, but I do not know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

check is something is selected before load images.

when create the listbox add

```
list1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", on_item_selected)
```

then add the function

```
def (on_item_selected):

    path = files[list1.curselection()[0]]
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    label = Label(ImageFrame)
    label.image = img
    label.configure(image=img)
```

on open....

```
if list1.curselection():
    path = files[list1.curselection()[0]]
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    label = Label(ImageFrame)
    label.image = img
    label.configure(image=img)
```

Comment: I change my code - no errors by nothing displays also

Comment: It' s normal, now you have to add a function that load image when you select a row of the listbox.

Comment: Yes, I understand that now, by I do not know how to load an image then..

Answer (score 0):

Here's runnable code, but it's merely a more complete version of @1966bc's answer which I created because you have in your question isn't a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
import glob
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def on_item_selected(event):
    path = files[list1.curselection()[0]]
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(path))
    label.image = img
    label.configure(image=img)


root = Tk()
page1 = Frame(root)
page1.grid(row=0, column=0)
ViewFrame = Frame(page1)
ViewFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

files = glob.glob('*.jpg')[:10]  # Limit to first 10 for development.
listvar = StringVar(value=files)
list1= Listbox(ViewFrame, height=15, width=75, listvariable=listvar)
list1.grid()

ImageFrame = LabelFrame(page1, text="Podgląd i parametry")
ImageFrame.grid(row=6, column=6, pady=10, padx=5)
label = Label(ImageFrame) # Create placeholder.
label.grid()

list1.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>", on_item_selected)
root.mainloop()
```